# How to implement a Save to Lightbox functionality without user registration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm building a Stock Photography site for internal purposes in WordPress and I want to have that save to lightbox function like in iStock or shutterstock. I want to our users to do this without them registering to the site because the page should be free for all and doesn't require them to buy the images. It's for internal use only.

[This WordPress theme has the save to lightbox function which I'm looking for](http://graphpaperpress.com/themes/stock-photography/#demo-full)

But I don't want to buy that theme because I already have a working theme which I'm working for.

I don't mind if the user would lose the lightbox if they close the browser or shutdown their computer. I just want them to collect what they want and them download it for later.

Does this have anything to do with HTML5 local storage? or any jquery plugin which I can use?

Comment: Research for JS/jQuery cookies here and also for [PHP session cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&pagesize=50&q=%5bphp%5d%20%2bsessions%20%2bcookie).

Answer (score 0):

A 'lightbox' is a 'modal' view. [deleted]

Comment: I know that it's kinda confusing for web designers nowadays the word "lightbox" because its stuck with that jquery plugin that enables a modal window for images.

Comment: But...

What I meant about lightbox in this context is the lightbox which stock photography sites uses. Before the web, lightbox means choosing images and saving it for later view which architects or interior designers use. 

if you open the link that I gave above, you will see exactly what I mean.

Comment: I stand corrected! A "lightbox" is clearly a thing related to photography. Didn't know that. In Wordpress [maybe leave this post up because it's tagged Wordpress], there is a very popular plugin called "Lightbox", and as a general case in web design a lightbox is a modal view. So there's that. You're question is about a specific feature of this specific commercial theme. Actually, your asked it clearly, I was just confused from a web design point of view.